# Traversing multiple CSV in SQL

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have a SQL Server 2008 database. This database has a stored procedure that will update several records. The ids of these records are stored in a parameter that is passed in via a comma-delimited string. The property values associated with each of these ids are passed in via two other comma-delimited strings. It is assumed that the length (in terms of tokens) and the orders of the values are correct. For instance, the three strings may look like this:

```
Param1='1,2,3,4,5'
Param2='Bill,Jill,Phil,Will,Jack'
Param3='Smith,Li,Wong,Jos,Dee'
```

My challenge is, I'm not sure what the best way to actually go about parsing these three CSVs and updating the corresponding records are. I have access to a procedure named ConvertCSVtoTable, which converts a CSV to a temp table of records. So Param1 would return

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

after the procedure was called. I thought about a cursor, but then it seems to get really messy.

Can someone tell me/show me, what the best way to address this problem is?

Comment: Does the stored procedure give you an ID column in your temp table as well as a column for the actual value?

Comment: @AllenG, I doubt it does.  It is likely just a roll your own sql server split function.  It should not be that hard to rewrite to have an identity column, maybe even as an optional parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd give some thought to reworking the inputs to your procedure. Since you're running SQL 2008, my first choice would be to use a [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). My second choice would be to pass the parameters as XML. Your current method, as you already know, is a real headache and is more error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bulk load to insert values to tmp table after that PIVOT them and insert to proper one.